# DatePicker in ViewPager

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, datepicker, android-viewpager

I have simple ViewPager. Each screen is represented by a Fragment. I want to use button DatePicker, but I have problem with it.
I found [this](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/fragment/select_a_date_in_a_fragment/) but unfortunately to use viewpager I'm using support v4 package. In line dialog.Show(FragmentManager, null); I have error : Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager' to 'Android.App.FragmentTransaction'

How to use DatePicker in ViewPager? Anyone could help?

Comment: Remove `Android.App.FragmentTransaction` import and add `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction' ` make sure you are importing all Fragment and other fragment related components from same package

Comment: Unfortunetly it's not that.  Read answer to Giorgi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the DialogFragment you use as a base class is from support library and not the built in one in Android. So the namespace for DialogFragment should be `Android.Support.V4.App`

Comment: It's not working.  Problem is that my solution need Android.App DialogFragment, but to ViewPager I must use Android.Support.V4.App. I'm looking for another solution.

Comment: @straiser Why do you need to use Android.App DialogFragment ? Why can't you use from support library?

Comment: Lok at link from first post [link] (http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/fragment/select_a_date_in_a_fragment/) Support.v4 doesnt have DatePickerDialog ( because this solution is created for Adroid.App) which I use to create DatePicker. That's why I'm looking for another solution of my problem.

Comment: I'm so stupid, and you're so right :) Change ` class DatePickerDialogFragment : DialogFragment` to ` class DatePickerDialogFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment` and works perfect. My bad :)